# Netbeans + glassfish on windows

Tags: windows, netbeans, glassfish

I download netbeans+glassfish for windows. And add this settings for glassfish:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx1400m
-Xss128k
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms1400m
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+AggressiveHeap
-server
```

But even deploy a simple Java EE app takes more than 5 minutes. On ubuntu it takes one minute but now I can't use linux. So, what I do wrong?

Comment: GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2 and NetBeans 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using GlassFish out-of-the-box, i.e. without any settings ?

GlassFish should typically start in about 2-3 seconds and the app deployment should be fairly straightforward and simple.

Comment: I run glassfish domain from asadmin and deploy into from netbeans. Probably glasshish restart all times when  my app deployed.